# Jquery click only work once on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the following script to show a different background depending on the state of the div.

When it is not expanded it shows the "plus (+)" sign, while when is expanded it does not have background image (does not shows anything).

The problem there is that only work once, and I dont know why.

Here's the code:

EDIT (added HTML)!

HTML:

```
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="wrapper wf">
            <ul id="Parks" class="just">
<!--------------- PRODUCT -->
                <li class="mix" href="#therapy_vital" >
                <div class="meta name">
                        <div class="img_wrapper">
                            <img src="images/spa/masaje/.jpg" onload="imgLoaded(this)"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="titles">
                            <h2>TITLE</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Expand -->
                    <div href="#therapy_vital" class="nav-toggle"></div>
                    <div id="therapy_vital" style="display:none">
                <article class="ac-small">
                 SUBCONTENT<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                 </article>
                </div>
                </li> 
<!--------------- PRODUCT -->
                <li class="mix" href="#therapy_natur" >
                <div class="meta name">
                        <div class="img_wrapper">
                            <img src="images/spa/masaje/.jpg" onload="imgLoaded(this)"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="titles">
                            <h2>TITLE</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Expand -->
                    <div href="#therapy_natur" class="nav-toggle"></div>
                    <div id="therapy_natur" style="display:none">
                <article class="ac-small">
                 SUBCONTENT<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                 </article>
                </div>
                            </li> 
</ul>
</div>                      
        </section>
    </body>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.meta').click(function() {
        $(this).css('background', 'none');
    });
    $('.mix').click(function() {
        var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');
        var toggle = $(this);
        $('.meta').click(function() {
            $(this).css('background', 'url(images/arrow_down.png) no-repeat scroll 95% 97% transparent');
        });
        $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function() {});
    });
});
```

(The .mix value makes the Div expands, and the .meta class switch to different background).

Any clue?

EDIT2 (Live example)

http://anubisfiles.com/test/test.html

(Due I am not really familiar with jsFiddle, I prefer to show you it hosted on a website).

Thanks!

Comment: create a fiddle or post you html too

Comment: you have two assignments of click to .meta, one when the document loads and one if .mix is clicked. If .meta is inside .mix or vice versa, you may want to cancel the event bubbling with e.stopPropagation()

Comment: your example is not working. Just add a fiddle. it'll  be easy to edit check then.

Comment: It is working on Firefox / Safari

Answer (score 0):

Use on function to bind events,

```
$('element').on('click', function() {

});
```

Comment: No. Not at all. For dynamic bindings, its better to use 'on'.

Comment: it works the same if the object exists at bind time. Yes you can save yourself grief by ALWAYS using .on, but I doubt it is the issue in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.mix').click(function() {
        var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');
        var toggle = $(this);

        $(this).find('.meta').css('background', 'url(images/arrow_down.png) no-repeat scroll 95% 97% transparent');
        $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function() {});
    });
```

Try this

Comment: I am not sure about this. need to see your html also.

Comment: Does not work, still showing the "Plus (+)" sign, while is expanded or not.