# Optimize load time in a website (200+ product images at the same page)

Tags: jquery, html, time, load

I am worried about a little problem of loading time that takes on a website.

At this moment I am working on a website which has 200+ product images on the same page (there's a jQuery filter usage which makes them filter depending on the filters), and I am not sure is the best way, because the page takes time to load and the images may break or slow the browser.

In the other hand I thought that maybe a "loading page" or some kind of jQuery could be a great solution until all the images are loaded.

(Also, there is a handicap because the images are optimized for tablet (not retina) so the images may be bigger than for a normal display on computer screen).

Any kind of solution?

Comment: I don't think the user want to wait until all the images are loaded to view the page. If paging is not an option, you may want smaller version of the images rendered if the requester is not a tablet

Comment: I thought that would be a great idea, but what will happens with optimization of the website? I'm just having the same image twice (depending on the device). Not sure at all

Comment: With the current state of technology, disk space should not be a problem. Of course, it depends on your use case. But for my website, with around 100,000 images x 2 versions, it works well.

Comment: Hey @HoàngLong how did u optimized that website? because about that amount of images should be a optimization troubles for you. By the way, can you share the url of any demo or the real website to check out how is it working?

Answer (score 1):

There are two common solutions.

### Pages (or soft pages)

You can have about a pageful of images loaded at one time, and have Next and Prev buttons.  Measure the average time on one page for a user, and start loading the second page around that time.  Once they click the button, you can fade out your current page, and fade in the next one.

Pros:

- reduces scrolling
- better than multiple pages
- cool transitions
- can fallback to simple page navigation when JS is disabled (if implemented properly on your server)

Cons:

- requires a button press (gets annoying when there's a lot of pages)

### Infinite Scrolling

There are a number of plugins that allow 'infinite scrolling'.  Basically, you get to the bottom of the page, and it loads more images from your server.

Pros:

- touch devices are optimized for scrolling
- no need to click buttons

Cons:

- most wait until you're at the bottom of the page, which causes you to wait a few seconds before the next batch of images are loaded
- no easy way to get to a certain page without waiting for all other images to load, unless you implement pushState

---

I started working on a plugin to handle infinite scrolling gracefully.  Currently, it's slightly better than other solutions I've seen.

## [inteliscroll](https://gist.github.com/brigand/6390896)

Usage:

1. Create a template for your image

   ```
       <span id="imageTemplate">
           <img src="" alt="my image"/>
       </span>
   ```
2. Add some images

   ```
   var images = ['img/img0001', 'img/img...'];
   ```

   You'll probably use a loop.  For example

   ```
   for (var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
       var padding = "0000".slice(i.toString().length);
       images.push(["img/kitten", padding, i].join(""));
   }
   ```
3. Initialize the plugin using your plugin

   ```
   var $imageTemplate = $('#imageTemplate');
   $imageTemplate.inteliscroll.addImages(images);
   $imageTemplate.inteliscroll();
   ```
4. Scroll

My todo list:

- implement momentum loading sizes
- performance testing
- compatibility
- Google Closure Compiler integration (WIP)
- *(maybe)* allow scrolling divs, as opposed to the window

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the support, but seems like I need a single page full of products, so the first option is not available. The second one seems good enough to solve the problem but I am not sure about that time waiting to show up the next batch of images. 

What about using some plugin to show up a loadbar until the web is full loaded? Maybe a little bit annoying? Is better to show directly the products? I am just afraid of that "cool" things...

Comment: I recommend loading two screen-heights of products at a time.  For most screens, this is about 30 thumbnails and short descriptions.  On mobile it's less, which is good to conserve data usage.  When there is one page beneath the user, load another page.  If the user is hits the bottom of the content before the next set of images is loaded, do 2 screenfuls next time, and then 3 with some reasonable upper limit.  This way people who take their time won't download excessive amounts of images.  Those who scroll fast won't be delayed as much.

Comment: I'm going to write an intelli scroll plugin, and I'll add another comment when it's finished.

Comment: Great I'll be waiting for your answer

Comment: @XaviAlsina, I have an alpha quality preview of what it can do.  I'm still adding a few features (listed in the question) and improving performance.  It's working good for me on a 1000 image test set (200px by 150px-ish).

Comment: Hey @FaceRainBrigand , I will test it now, the main problem there is that template you mentioned, because the one I am using can't be modified (u will understand in few seconds).

I will let you see how works my product page. It expands the div to show further information, so will be dificult to modify the template assuming your script.

http://anubisfiles.com/test/test.html

As u can see, I am using a different sort of js because each one does a different fuction. One creates he Div, and the other ones is for the filtering script.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: By the way @FakeRainBrigand do u know how to solve this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484117/jquery-click-only-work-once-on-toggle because still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Use [LazyLoad](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

[LazyLoad](https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload/)

And other similar jquery plugins

Comment: This is a link only answer. Try elaborating your answer as to how lazy loading will be helpful.

Comment: Hey Amit, thanks for that answer. I'm checking this out! 

By the way, as Narendra pointed, would be great a little explanation of what it does / how it works.